# preg_split every character, but don't split if is quote

Tags: php, arrays, regex, utf-8, preg-split

I'm using the following code to split my UTF-8 strings to characters:

```
$characters = preg_split('//u', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

In some cases, a character might have a single quote after it. for example: `hel'lo`. I want to keep that quote with the character before it.

Using the regex above, my array is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => h
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => '
    [4] => l
    [5] => o
)
```

And I want the array to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => h
    [1] => e
    [2] => l'
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
)
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!

(the single quote can be at the beginning of the string, at the end of it and in the middle of it).

Comment: I would not use `preg_split` if you deal with UTF8 strings. I'd recommend `preg_match_all("~\X'?~u", $s, $m)` to get all Unicode chars with an optional `'` after them. Your other cases with an initial `'` are not clear to me, please add details to the question.

Comment: Please show your expected results when splitting `'hello` and `hello'`.  With the first sample, there is no character before the single quote -- should the `'` be by itself or bound to the `h`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `split`, you can do `preg_match_all` using

```
'?\p{L}'?
```

i.e. an optional `'` before and after the Unicode letter:

```
preg_match_all("/'?\\p{L}'?/u", $str, $matches);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVRMuQ/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` to prevent from split

```
$characters = preg_split("/(?!')/u", $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```